# Problem updating rlang when installing dev version of a package

Tags: r, tidyr, rlang, install.packages

I'm trying to install the dev version of `tidyr`. When I try `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")` or `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")`, I get the following error:

```
> devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/tidyr@master
Downloading GitHub repo r-lib/vctrs@master
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1:   All
2:   CRAN packages only
3:   None
4:   rlang    (0.3.4 -> 18856f22a...) [GitHub]
5:   ellipsis (0.1.0 -> 9908b24a2...) [GitHub]

Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1: 1
rlang    (0.3.4 -> 18856f22a...) [GitHub]
ellipsis (0.1.0 -> 9908b24a2...) [GitHub]
Downloading GitHub repo r-lib/rlang@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYDrYNh\remotes96bc1c295445\r-lib-rlang-18856f2/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'rlang': (2s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  installing the package to process help pages (1.3s)
-  cleaning src (27.6s)
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (445ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories (878ms)
-  building 'rlang_0.3.4.9002.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/00LOCK-rlang'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYDrYNh/file96bc24b12ee3/rlang_0.3.4.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I remove `00LOCK-rlang` as suggested by the warning and try again. As before, I get asked which packages I want to update and I select `All`. This time I get the following error when it attempts to update `rlang`:

```
installing to C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang/libs/x64
Error in file.copy(files, dest, overwrite = TRUE) : 
  (converted from warning) problem copying .\rlang.dll to C:\Users\owner\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
* removing 'C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
Error in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) : 
  (converted from warning) problem copying C:\Users\owner\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\owner\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
Execution halted
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYDrYNh/file96bc74433a2d/rlang_0.3.4.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Session info after second attempt:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.0     devtools_2.0.2    pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.3.4       tools_3.5.2       pkgbuild_1.0.3   
[11] sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.0.4     yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.18     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.3.0   
[21] callr_3.2.0       fs_1.2.7          ps_1.3.0          curl_3.3          rpart_4.1-15      testthat_2.0.1    glue_1.3.1        memoise_1.1.0     compiler_3.5.2    desc_1.2.0       
[31] backports_1.1.4   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Using `source("https://install-github.me/r-lib/rlang")` solved the problem but why did `devtools::` and `remotes::install_github()` fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced this issue as well. Note the `[...]\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied`. The current R-session is not permitted to access these files. To circumvent this, open `Rgui.exe` by either searching for `Rgui` in Windows Search via `Win+Q`, or by the `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe`. Right-click and press `Run as administrator`, and then do the same thing, as you did before.

You could also run RStudio in Administrative mode.

Comment: I had the same problem. Running R as administrator did not work for me. Running RStudio as administrator did not work either. Running Rgui as administrator solve the problem. I don't understand the reason, but it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Mossa, it wouldn't have occurred to me to use the gui - why would there be a difference between installing it there vs RStudio? I had tried running RStudio as admin but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 8):

I found a slightly different solution.

1. Open Rgui.exe as Administrator. I don't think you actually need to open Rgui.exe as Administrator but I did so I'll leave it.
2. Move `C:\...\R\win-library\3.5\rlang` to another folder (leaving no rlang folder in that directory)
3. `install.packages("rlang")`
4. Close Rgui
5. Start a new (normal) session and enjoy!

Comment: This worked for me on a computer which I don't have administrative privileges. Also, I did not move the rlang folder. I just did [step 1] + [step 3] and it worked.